# Tensorflow batch norm leading to the imbalance between training loss and validation loss?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

The code snippet bellow is my code. I use Queues to load training data, and use Feed to load validation images . Along with the training process, the training loss and training accuracy just goes right. However, as for validation phase, the validation losses and the accuracy are just weird. The validation loss is too high, and the validation accuracy is too low no matter how many steps I run, and it just like random guess. However, when I set the 'is_training' parameter to True instead of False in function load_validate_img_data, the validation losses and accuracy just goes right . Is there something wrong with the use of the batch_norm?

```
def inference(inputs,
            num_classes=1000,
            is_training=True,
            dropout_keep_prob=0.5,
            reuse = None,
            scope='alexnet'):




      with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected],
                        normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
                        activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                        biases_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1),
                        weights_regularizer=slim.l2_regularizer(WEIGHT_DECAY),
                        normalizer_params={'is_training': is_training, 
                        'decay': 0.95, 'reuse':reuse, 'scope': scope}):

            with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d], padding='SAME'):

                with slim.arg_scope([slim.max_pool2d], padding='VALID') :

                    with tf.variable_scope(scope, [inputs],reuse = reuse) as sc:



                            net = slim.conv2d(inputs, 32, [3, 3],2, scope='conv1', padding='VALID')
                            net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], 2, scope='pool1')

                            net = slim.conv2d(net, 64, [3, 3], scope='conv2')
                            net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], 2, scope='pool2')

                            net = slim.conv2d(net, 128, [2, 2], scope='conv3')
                            net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], 2, scope='pool3')

                            net = slim.conv2d(net, 256, [2, 2], scope='conv4')
                            net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], 2, scope='pool4')

                            net = slim.conv2d(net, 512, [2, 2], scope='conv5')
                            net = slim.avg_pool2d(net, [2, 2],  scope='pool5')



                            net = slim.dropout(net, dropout_keep_prob, is_training=is_training, scope='dropout6')

                            net = slim.conv2d(net, num_classes,[1,1]  ,activation_fn = None, normalizer_fn = None, scope='fc7')
                            net = tf.squeeze(net, [1, 2], name='fc8/squeezed')
                            end_points = net

                            return net, end_points

def get_softmax_loss(logits, labels, name = 'train'):


    one_hot_labels = slim.one_hot_encoding(labels, LABEL_NUM)

    softmax_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = one_hot_labels, logits = logits))

    vars = tf.trainable_variables()
    regularization_loss = tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in vars]) * 0.0005


    total_loss = softmax_loss + regularization_loss



    return total_loss

def get_train_op(loss):


    lr_in_use = tf.Variable(0.01, trainable=False)
    with tf.name_scope('lr_update'):       
        lr_update = tf.assign(lr_in_use, tf.maximum(lr_in_use*0.5, 0.000001))


    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(lr_in_use, 0.9)


    step = tf.get_variable("step", [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)
    train_op = slim.learning.create_train_op(loss, optimizer, global_step = step)



    loss_update = loss
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    if update_ops:
        updates = tf.group(*update_ops)
        loss_update = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([updates], loss)



    return train_op, loss_update, lr_update

def get_train_acc(logits, labels, name = 'train'):

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.arg_max(logits, 1), labels), tf.float32))

    return accuracy

def load_validate_img_data():



    validate_img_root = '~/data/'

    img_roots = glob(validate_img_root + '*.bmp')

    validate_img = []
    validate_label = []
    read_count = 0
    for root in img_roots:

        if read_count == 400:
            break

        label_root = root.split('/')
        validate_label.append(label_root[-1][:-4])
        validate_img.append(cv2.imread(root))

        read_count += 1



    validate_img = np.array(validate_img).astype(np.float32)
    validate_label = np.array(validate_label).astype(np.int64)


    with tf.name_scope('validate_input'):
        input_imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (100, ORIGINAL_SIZE[0], ORIGINAL_SIZE[1], CHANNELS), name = 'imgs')
        input_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape = (100), name = 'labels')
    transfer_input_imgs = ut._resize_crop_img(input_imgs, RESIZE_TO, RESIZE_TO, process_type = 'validate')



    logits, out_data = face_train.inference(transfer_input_imgs,  num_classes=LABEL_NUM, is_training = False, reuse = True)


    validate_accuracy = get_train_acc(logits, input_labels, name = 'validate')
    validate_loss = get_softmax_loss(logits, input_labels, name = 'validate')



    return validate_img, validate_label, input_imgs, input_labels, validate_accuracy, validate_loss

with tf.Graph().as_default():



    images, labels = ut._load_batch_t(data_dir, ORIGINAL_SIZE, CHANNELS, BATCH_SIZE, RESIZE_TO, RESIZE_TO)


    logits= face_train.inference(images,  num_classes=LABEL_NUM)


    accuracy = get_train_acc(logits, labels)

    total_loss = get_softmax_loss(logits, labels)
    train_op, loss_update, lr_update = get_train_op(total_loss)




    validate_img, validate_label, img_placeholer,label_placeholder, validate_accuracy, validate_loss = load_validate_img_data()



    with tf.Session() as sess:



        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())


        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), max_to_keep=10000)





        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()  
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord) 

        total_step = 0
        epoc_step = int(SAMPLE_NUM/BATCH_SIZE)
        for epoc in range(EPOC_NUM):
            for step in range(epoc_step):



                _ = sess.run([train_op])


                if total_step % 20 == 0:
                    loss, train_ac  =sess.run([loss_update, accuracy])
                    print ('epoc : %d, step : %d, train_loss : %.2f, train_acc: %.3f' %(epoc, step, loss, train_ac))




                if total_step % 200 == 0:
                    all_va_acc = 0
                    all_va_loss = 0

                    for i in range(4):

                        feed_dict = {img_placeholer: validate_img[i*100 : (i+1)*100],  \
                       label_placeholder: validate_label[i*100 : (i+1)*100]}

                        va_acc, va_loss, summary_val= sess.run([validate_accuracy, validate_loss, merged_val ], feed_dict = feed_dict)
                        all_va_acc += va_acc
                        all_va_loss += va_loss


                    print ('validate_accuracy: %.2f,  validate_loss: %.2f' % (all_va_acc/4.0, all_va_loss/4.0))



                total_step += 1




        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 0):

During inference, batch norm `moving average mean` and `moving average variance` are used, so you need to set the parameter `is_training` as False.

```
def inference(inputs,
        num_classes=1000,
        is_training=False,
        dropout_keep_prob=0.5,
        reuse = None,
        scope='alexnet'):
```

Comment: I have figured out what happened and I have made a stupid mistake. I use the normolized image data(0,1) to train, but use unnormolized image data(0, 255) to test. But still thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you still get weirdly big loss values and weirdly small accuracy values when using `is_training=False` in the `tf.layers.batch_normalization()` for evaluation, you need to keep in mind the following:

> Note: when training, the moving_mean and moving_variance need to be updated. By default the update ops are placed in tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, so they need to be added as a dependency to the train_optf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, so they need to be added as a dependency to the train_op

In order to fix this issue you need to wrap your `train_op` in the scope containing the dependencies just like that:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16455